# If a=b, how does a-b=0?

Tags: ring-theory

Let R be a ring and let $a,b \in R$.

Suppose $a=b$. How do you know that $a +- b=0$?

In other words, what axiom or step lets you say that $a +-b = b + -b$? (That you can add the same thing to both sides of the equation.)

Comment: That's not a ring axiom, that's a logical-equality axiom.

Comment: @ktm5124 I think Git Gud hit it on the nail as to the main idea of what you're asking, but in addition you *do* need closure under addition and existence of inverse element to justify your particular case.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from an incomplete understanding of the symbol “$=$”. It *must* be kept in mind that the two sides of the equals sign are different designations for a single thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making substitutions like that is always allowable. Essentially, all we're trying to say there is that
$$a=b$$
implies
$$f(a)=f(b)$$
(where $f$ here is "add $-b$"). But we  don't need any special axioms for our ring to do this; this is just how equality works in all cases.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks!

Comment: It's not really how *equality* works, it's how *functions* work. And saying that addition of a fixed element is a function does the trick. The defining properties of a function guarantee this behavior.